# Error dimensioning an array to a dynamic size

Tags: vba

The following code:

```
Sub mySub()

    Dim s As String
    s = "jdsjakfjdaskl"
    Dim a(Len(s)) As String

End Sub
```

Gives an error

> "Compile error: Constant expression required".

I would really appreciate any advice on how to fix this, thanks!

Comment: Dim a(Len(s)) As String  --- is it legal??

Comment: No it's not - what are you trying to achieve @MrRay_ME?

Comment: Please [edit] your question title to something meaningful. You've simply repeated the tag information. Your title should describe the question you're asking or problem you're experiencing, and should be detailed enough to be useful to future readers who see it in a search result. Simply repetitively typing the tag info isn't useful or relevant.

Comment: `Len(s)` is not a "constant expression" - it's not evaluated at compile-time, but at run-time.  In contrast, `Dim a(13) As String` would be fine, becuase `13` is known at compile-time.

Comment: ...if you need to size an array at *run-time* use `ReDim()`

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `ReDim` if you wish the size of an array to be set at run-time:

```
Sub mySub()

    Dim s As String
    Dim a() As String
    s = "jdsjakfjdaskl"
    ReDim a(1 To Len(s)) As String
    'The "As String" in the above statement is optional as it already knows
    'it is of type String, so you can simplify that if you like to:
    'ReDim a(1 To Len(s))

End Sub
```

Comment: You already `Dim a() As String` , you can settle for `ReDim a(1 To Len(s))`

Comment: @ShaiRado - I just like to put it in both places so that I don't get confused - I'll add in a comment to the answer though, just so the OP knows it is optional.

Comment: @ShaiRado - never even heard of it - I'm now googling it to see what it is about :D

Comment: Anyway, they say that every character, even "space-bar" costs memory and CPU in some way. I wonder if it's true (or just for the show)

Comment: @ShaiRado - I remember when I was programming things on a HP71B with a 16K (or was it 4K) memory limit, and variable names could be 1 character or 1 character and 1 digit (e.g. "A" or "B5").  The variable took one byte if it was one character, or 1.5 bytes if it was a character+digit.  So I wrote a program to count how many times each variable was used in our programs so that we could use the single character variable names for the most used ones - thus saving as many 4 bits as possible.